# Stop org-mode from defining agenda files in custom

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, custom

I have the following line in my `.emacs`:

```
(setq org-agenda-files (directory-files "~/org-files" 'absolute "[^#]*.org$" 'no-sort))
```

I would like for `org-agenda-files` to be defined in this way on startup. However, a `(custom-set-variables '(org-agenda-files ...))` keeps getting populated, which means that whenever I remove `.org` files on another computer, I get hit with `Non-existent agenda file` messages. How can I remove this persistent behavior?

Comment: Do you use custom settings for anything else? Would not loading *any* custom variables be a solution?

Comment: It would be for me! I don't use custom settings for anything. I prefer to control my settings explicitly through elisp.

Answer (score 2):

You might be typing `C-c [` which invokes `(org-agenda-file-to-front)`. See http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-files.html

Redefine that key so that it does not mess with the agenda list (saving the changes in `emacs-custom.el`), and your issue should go away.

Answer (score 2):

One solution to stop Emacs from modifying your custom settings is to not use custom settings at.  Setting the variable `custom-file` to some filename will cause custom settings to be stored in that file.  The default is `nil`, which means to use your init file.

You can then load the custom settings with `(load custom-file)`. Or not load them and then whatever goes in there is basically going into black hole.  On Linux, you can send them to a more literal black hole by setting `custom-file` to `/dev/null`. It's a little passive-aggressive, but it works.