# Gather all tagged text in one document a la LogSeq

Tags: org-mode, org-tags, tags

Is it possible to have a flow in Emacs similar to `LogSeq` whereby the user can call one tag (e.g., #quotes) and have a buffer filled with all the text that matches such tag? I suppose the closer thing is to do grep, but I was wondering if there was something more sophisticated that would collect all the entire blocks belonging to a specific tag. Thanks!

Solution here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/70981/15546

Comment: A method like [the one described here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html) would allow you to do a tags search in a set of Org mode files and collect all the matches in one buffer, but that would be only the headlines. You can easily get to the full text of the headline (in a different buffer) by pressing `SPACE`. Not sure whether that meets your requirements though.  See the [Org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html#Matching-tags-and-properties) for some details on this kind of search.

Comment: In fact, the above mechanism can be used to export the agenda with not just the headlines but (depending on the option `org-agenda-add-entry-text-maxlines`) part or all of the body of each headline as well.

Comment: I will have a look, thanks! It seems that I can search beyond my agenda files, which is the purpose as I want to search within newly created notes.

Comment: I'm having trouble setting the example under "Making the most of local settings".  Not sure how many brackets to use when using add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands as opposed to using setq org-agenda-custom-commands. I'm getting errors.

Comment: You might find @gusbrs's comments in [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70954/struggling-to-set-org-agenda-files-per-org-agenda-custom-command) useful.

Comment: Check my answer to the linked question and see if it helps you with this one.

Comment: Solution here for this problem: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/70981/15546